# Volume of water in a tilted hemispherical bowl

Tags: geometry, solution-verification, 3d

Suppose you have a hemispherical bowl that is open at the top.  You tilt the bowl by an angle $\theta$ in any direction.  Then you fill it with water till the water surface reaches the lowest point on the rim of the bowl.  If the radius of the bowl is $R$, what is the volume $V$ of water as a function of $\theta$?

**My approach:**

Let the center of the bowl's top be at the origin of the coordinate frame. Rotate the bowl about the $x$ axis by $\theta$, then the minimum elevation of the rim's circle is at $(0,  R \cos \theta, - rR \sin \theta ) $.  So we want to fill the spherical cap between $z = -R$ and $z = - R \sin \theta $ with water.  The height of this cap is $h = R (1 - \sin \theta)$
so from the table in [this Wikipedia page on Spherical Cap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap), we get the volume as

$ V = \dfrac{\pi h^2}{3} ( 3 R - h )  $

Substituting $h$,

$ V = \dfrac{\pi}{3} R^3 (1 - \sin \theta)^2 ( 2 + \sin \theta) $

The ratio of this volume to the maximum bowl volume (which is $\dfrac{2 \pi}{3} $ is given by

$ f(\theta) = \dfrac{1}{2} (1 - \sin \theta)^2 (2 + \sin \theta) $

Below is the graph of this function.  As expected it is a decreasing function, that reaches $0$ at $\theta = \dfrac{\pi}{2} $

[image]

Comment: You present a soulution to the initial question, what do you expect me to answer now?

Comment: You don't have to answer.